# how to use String method inside while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java-io

i am trying to use String method inside while loop so i can read part of the file the code is this

```
   package AnimeAid;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ReadFile {


    public void getFileInformation() throws IOException {   

        try{
        String file;
        file = "tra.srt";
        Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
        Path path = Paths.get(file);
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, charset);
        System.out.printf("Lines from %s:%n",file);
        String line;
        int num = 5;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null && line.indexOf(':') != -1){
            System.out.println(line.substring(0, 10));


        }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

now it not give me any error message but it is not giving the right answer and i need to use return not system.out.print

```
       Lines from tra.srt:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

how file look like

```
 1
00:00:01,600 --> 00:00:04,080
<b>Mr Magnussen, please state your
full name for the record.</b>

2
00:00:04,080 --> 00:00:07,040
Charles Augustus Magnussen.
```

the output most be the timing `00:00:01,600` from every line how he know by looking for every `:` sign

Comment: Consider using StringBuffer or StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
line.indexOf(':')
```

returns an integer. This means you have `while (boolean && int)` which makes no sense in a Java world. You should compare the result of the `indexOf` method in order to get there a boolean as well.

Eg:

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null && line.indexOf(':') != -1)
```

Comment: thank you are right but still i can't get it work because of the line i need to tell java that when ever is the file not empty and that the line have the mark ":" substring it but line as refrense is wrong

Comment: can you tell me how to fix it plz i am looking around for two days

Comment: No, not if you don't provide me the exact error message.

Comment: The line is probably not really 8 characters long. You are trying to take a substring which is larger than the original string.

Comment: look for the update please and it is better if the he looked for two sign : : not one

Comment: Let me be Sherlock today: your condition inside the while loop should probably be an if. Try: `while((line = ...) != null) { if (line.indexOf(':') != -1) { ... } }`.

Comment: thanks dude i love you,by the way you look like romeo from the movie

Comment: Which movie? I thought I actually looked a bit like Sherlock himself :)